# Inserting data into a table from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I insert data into a table from multiple tables where all the tables have a common prefix as their table name

This is the structure of the table and error table generated by the package (DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG) :

```
Name                             Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_ID                       VARCHAR2(20)
EFFECTIVE_DTM                    DATE
ACCOUNT_STATUS                   VARCHAR2(200)
STATUS_REASON_TXT                VARCHAR2(255)
ISVALID                          NUMBER(1)


Name                                   Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORA_ERR_NUMBER                         NUMBER
ORA_ERR_MESG$                          VARCHAR2(2000)
ORA_ERR_ROWID$                         ROWID
ORA_ERR_OPTYP$                         VARCHAR2(2)
ORA_ERR_TAG$                           VARCHAR2(2000)
ACCOUNT_ID                             VARCHAR2(4000)
EFFECTIVE_DTM                          VARCHAR2(4000)
ACCOUNT_STATUS                         VARCHAR2(4000)
STATUS_REASON_TXT                      VARCHAR2(4000)
ISVALID                                VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Comment: What is the table structure of the common tables?

Comment: Which DBMS using..?Specify your sample data and expected result

Comment: Can you send use a sample of your code or just send use the table structure.

Comment: The common tables are actually created by the procedure DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG  , so the table names start with 'ERR$_'  . The table structure of these common tables is that first five columns are added by the procedure and the remaining columns are by the table it is referring to if errored

Answer (score 0):

For starting you can `select` from all your source tables in union/union all queries if you know all the table names. Otherwise you can use the pl/sql block to use dynamic query to do this task for you.

But it would be easier to state if you provide your table structure and few records and some effort done by you as commented by peers in comment section.

**Edit**

After getting further clarity on the requirement I would suggest to keep all the other columns (basically entries from the base tables) into one single column - we can use `CLOB` for this purpose.
you can try something like below -

*** considering err log table as -

```
create table err_log_tab (

ORA_ERR_NUMBER                         NUMBER,
ORA_ERR_MESG$                          VARCHAR2(2000),
ORA_ERR_ROWID$                         ROWID,
ORA_ERR_OPTYP$                         VARCHAR2(2),
ORA_ERR_TAG$                           VARCHAR2(2000),
table_name                             varchar2(50),
row_data                               clob)
```

Below block can be executed to do so -

```
DECLARE
   l_sql     VARCHAR2(4000);
   l_col_cnt NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

   FOR l_err_tabs IN (SELECT table_name
                        FROM user_tab_cols
                       WHERE table_name LIKE 'ERR$_%'
                         AND column_name IN ('ORA_ERR_NUMBER',
                                             'ORA_ERR_MESG$',
                                             'ORA_ERR_ROWID$',
                                             'ORA_ERR_OPTYP$',
                                             'ORA_ERR_TAG$')
                       GROUP BY table_name
                      HAVING COUNT(*) = 5)
   LOOP
      l_sql := 'insert into err_log_tab select ORA_ERR_NUMBER,ORA_ERR_MESG$,ORA_ERR_ROWID$,ORA_ERR_OPTYP$,ORA_ERR_TAG$,''' ||
               substr(l_err_tabs.table_name,
                      6) || ''' table_name , to_clob(' || chr(10);
      FOR l_cols IN (SELECT column_name
                       FROM user_tab_cols
                      WHERE table_name = l_err_tabs.table_name
                        AND column_id > 5
                      ORDER BY column_id)
      LOOP
         l_sql := l_sql || CASE
                     WHEN l_col_cnt = 1 THEN
                      '||'',''||'
                     ELSE
                      ''
                  END || '''"''||' || l_cols.column_name || '||''"''';
         l_col_cnt := 1;

      END LOOP;
      l_sql := l_sql || ') row_data from ' || l_err_tabs.table_name;
      --dbms_output.put_line (l_sql);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;

   END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Please correct me if my understanding with question is going in wrong direction.

Comment: The multiple source tables have different table structures and they have just been created , so no rows/records exists . The corresponding error tables for these source tables  have been created by the package DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG . I need to create and insert into a table  all these error logs

Comment: Hi Pratik any suggestions??

Comment: Hi @span , your question introduced me with something new .. thanks .. 

as per my understanding with the question, we can still use dynamic query considering all tables starting with 'ERR$_%'. Please refer edition in my answer.